# DNS resolves incorrectly, even after purge

Tags: macos, network, dns

After changing a CNAME record on my DNS server, I am seeing issues with the DNS on my Macbook Air running OS X 10.10. Other computers on the same network resolves to the correct, new IP.

```
$ host beta.stoffiplayer.com
beta.stoffiplayer.com is an alias for polar-meadow-2518.herokuapp.com.
polar-meadow-2518.herokuapp.com is an alias for us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com.
us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com has address 54.243.37.192
```

This is correct, it is an alias for a Heroku app.

But when I try Chrome, Safari or even curl I get a different IP:

```
$ curl -vI http://beta.stoffiplayer.com/ 2>&1 | grep Connected 
* Connected to beta.stoffiplayer.com (52.16.117.175) port 80 (#0)
```

This IP does not belong to heroku.com but Amazon AWS:

```
$ host 52.16.117.175
175.117.16.52.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer ec2-52-16-117-175.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
```

I tried to purge the DNS cache but it doesn't make a difference:

```
$ sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache
$ sudo discoveryutil udnsflushcaches
$ curl -vI http://beta.stoffiplayer.com/ 2>&1 | grep Connected
* Connected to beta.stoffiplayer.com (52.16.117.175) port 80 (#0)
```

I have even rebooted the computer, but still same result.

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately, I cannot answer it. However I think this question would be better asked on  Server  Fault